Nvidia Settings shows simple in Wayland but Full in Xorg
Using Ubuntu 24.10 with Nvidia Driver 560 and when I open the Nvidia Settings it shows like this:

But if I use Xorg then it works properly and shows all options. Can I fix this without without changing back to Xorg again?

Not a new issue, see: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/wayland-support-for-nvidia-settings/189799/3  There is a suggestion to start a virtual term, startx, and a simple window manager to run nvidia-settings under xorg.

Does use of the "prime-select" cli change the settings that you need to change under Wayland?

I think that's normal behaviour. Why show X11 details under Wayland?

@heynnema Do you mean the Nvidia Settings, the options in it are for Xorg related cases? There are no options for Wayland in there? Like the fan speed, clock speed, ram speed, etc.. All of that is for Xorg only?

Thanks to @ubfan1 and @heynnema I was able to find out the Nvidia Settings app is (for now) an X11 only app. Meaning, Nvidia does not yet have an Nvidia Settings app for Wayland (Because of a long history of things going on here:
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/wayland-support-for-nvidia-settings/189799/25
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/ubuntu-24-and-560-proton-wine-games-do-not-run/305266/14
https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-settings/issues/69
Good news is that Nvidia is starting to work (As of October 2024) on Wayland as mentioned here:
https://www.phoronix.com/news/NVIDIA-Wayland-Roadmap-2024
Which includes:


You can find more here: https://indico.freedesktop.org/event/6/contributions/287/attachments/210/288/NVIDIA%20Wayland%20Roadmap.pdf
Anyway for now, I moved to X11 but I am happy there is a move to tackle this.
